# Mysql on Digital Ocean with Kubernetes not working

Tags: kubernetes, flask, sqlalchemy, mariadb, digital-ocean

I have a Flask kubernetes application with a Mariadb backend.  I have the application working locally on a MariaDB container, but now I need to move it to Digital Ocean.  I spun up the DB hosted by them and changed my connection string and added the SSL requirements, but it is unable to connect to the DB with the following error message.  I have played around with the DO settings and added the k8s cluster to the trusted resources.  Not sure what else to try.  I have verified from within the pod that the connection string is correct based on what is printed out by Digital Ocean.  I have also verified within the pod that the cert is in the right location.  Any idea on what I am missing?

```
connection string is mysql+pymysql://doadmin:password@private-db-mysql-abc-do-user-123-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:12345/defaultdb

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'private-db-mysql-abc-do-user123.db.ondigitalocean.com' (timed out)")
```

Flask SqlAlchemy connection

```
DBNAME = "database.db"

db = SQLAlchemy()

db_host = os.getenv('mysql_host')
db_user = os.getenv('mysql_username')
db_password = os.getenv('mysql_password')
database = os.getenv('mysql_database')
db_port = os.getenv('mysql_port')
connection_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{database}"



# This is only used in Prod
DB_SSL_CERT = "/app/db_cert/ca-certificate.crt"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)


    # SQL Alchemy Stuff

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = config('SECRET_KEY')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = connection_string
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_SSL_CA'] = DB_SSL_CERT

    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)
    # Set context to Alchemy
    # if not function wont work
    # https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/
    app.app_context().push()

    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        print(f'Created {DBNAME} Database!')
        
    return app
```